# Counterexample: convex function that is not logarithmically-convex.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Pretty much the title.

I am looking for a convex function that is not logarithmically convex. A simple reminder is that a function is logarithmically convex if and only if $\mathrm{log} f$ is convex. That is, if
\begin{align}
\mathrm{log} f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda \mathrm{log} f(x) + (1-\lambda)\mathrm{log}f(y).
\end{align}

Another tool someone has at his disposal is the famous second derivative criterion.

My thoughts are for the function $f(x) = x^2$ which as we know is convex, since $f''(x) = 2 > 0 \  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ but $\mathrm{log} f(x) = \mathrm{log}x^2$ has second derivative $(\log f(x))^{''} = \dfrac{-2}{x^2} < 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ implying that it is not convex but concave.

Is this true and sufficient or one would need something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's good enough, I think (although the final verdict is up to whoever is correcting your exams).

I might personally choose $x^2+1$, just to avoid any and all issues with the logarithm not being defined. The second derivative is a little more complicated, and not always negative:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln(x^2+1)=\frac{2(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$
But this second derivative is negative on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$, so $x^2+1$ is certainly not logarithmically concave.

Comment: Yours is also good enough. My main "problem" was the fact that I proved that $\log f(x)$ was concave which is another form of (inverse) convexity, and my worry was that it was getting complicated. 

At any rate, thanks for your input and I consider the matter closed.

Comment: @algevristis a very valid concern -- because there are functions (e.g. linear functions) which are both concave and convex simultaneously. However, for your example, your function is actually *strictly* concave, which would be sufficient (if your class has discussed this notion)

Comment: @Zim exactly, that's why I had been very careful to avoid discussion of linear expressions.

Answer (score 0):

another example is $f(x)=x$. It is clearly convex since it is linear. However, $\log(f(x))=\log(x)$ is nonconvex.

Comment: Amazing! That's very good too.